# Not able to run emulator in flutter with dart programing using android studio as IDE

Tags: emulation

> INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
> INFO | Found systemPath
> C:\Users\thambidurai\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox\google_apis_playstore\x86_64
> ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an
> experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable
> this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in:
> C:\Users\THAMBI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db,
> detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you
> wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
> INFO | IPv4 server found: 10.4.21.19

please try to help me to fix it

I try to run emulator using flutter with dart programing